# Using sfml, calling window.close() gives: *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated

Tags: c++, sfml

The program was running fine until I added the Peca class. Currently still runs until I call window.close(). I have sfml 2.5.1 installed and I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. Removing all references to the Peca class eliminates the problem, and so does removing window.close(). I read that having multiple versions of sfml might cause this, but I only seem to have one.

```
#include "Game.h"

int main(){
    Game game;
    game.run();
    return 0;
}
```

```
#include "Game.h"
#define TIMEPERFRAME sf::seconds(1.f/60.f)
#define GAMENAME "game name" 

Game::Game()
:    window(sf::VideoMode(500,600),GAMENAME, sf::Style::Default),
     peca()
{    
}

void Game::update(sf::Time timePerFrame){    
}

void Game::render(){    
}

void Game::run(){
    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time elapsedSinceUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;        

    while(window.isOpen()){
        processEvents();
        elapsedSinceUpdate += clock.restart();
        while(elapsedSinceUpdate > TIMEPERFRAME){
            elapsedSinceUpdate -= TIMEPERFRAME;
            processEvents();
            update(TIMEPERFRAME);
        }
        render();
    }

}

void Game::processEvents(){
    sf::Event event;
    while(window.pollEvent(event)){
        if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
            window.close();
        }
    }
}
```

```
#include "Peca.h"

Peca::Peca()
    :tile(4)
{
    tile.setPoint(0, sf::Vector2f(0, 0));
    tile.setPoint(1, sf::Vector2f(20, 10));
    tile.setPoint(2, sf::Vector2f(40, 0));
    tile.setPoint(3, sf::Vector2f(20, -10));

}

sf::ConvexShape Peca::getTile(){
    return tile;
}
```

Headers:

```
#ifndef __GAME__
#define __GAME__

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Peca.h"  

class Game{
    
    public:
        Game();
        void run();

    private:
        void processEvents();
        void update(sf::Time timePerFrame);
        void render();

        sf::RenderWindow window;
        Peca peca;

};

#endif
```

```
#ifndef __PECA__
#define __PECA__

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Peca{
    public:
        Peca();
        sf::ConvexShape getTile();

    private:
        sf::ConvexShape tile;

};

#endif
```

makefile:

```
run: jogo
    ./jogo

jogo: jogo.o Game.o Peca.o
    g++ jogo.o Game.o Peca.o -o jogo -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

jogo.o: jogo.cpp
    g++ -c jogo.cpp

Game.o: Game.cpp
    g++ -c Game.cpp

Peca.o: Peca.cpp
    g++ -c Peca.cpp
```

sfml version:

```
$ apt list libsfml-dev 
libsfml-dev/focal,now 2.5.1+dfsg-1build1 amd64 [installed]
```

Tried to use gdb and got this:

```
Core was generated by `./jogo'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7feb93078680 (LWP 27482))]
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007feb9388d859 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007feb938f83ee in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7feb93a2207c "*** %s ***: terminated\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:155
#3  0x00007feb9399ab4a in __GI___fortify_fail (msg=msg@entry=0x7feb93a22064 "stack smashing detected") at fortify_fail.c:26
#4  0x00007feb9399ab16 in __stack_chk_fail () at stack_chk_fail.c:24
#5  0x000055e2081cf4f3 in main ()
```

Comment: Compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and you'll probably see the exact call stack when this is happening.

Comment: I tried that, but still only shows the error

Comment: Did you try to both compile everything and link with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly im on windows but tested using ubuntu on wsl.

I stopped using make files as i always made errors in them so moved over to cmake.

My CMakeLists.txt for sfml is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(StackOverflow)

# Windows specific config
IF (WIN32)
    # Include local sfml cmake config
    set(SFML_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SFML-2.5.1/lib/cmake/SFML")
    # Link sfml statically (Optional)
    set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)
ENDIF()

find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS graphics audio REQUIRED)

FILE(
    GLOB
    SOURCES
    "src/*.cpp"
)

add_executable(StackOverflow ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(StackOverflow sfml-graphics sfml-audio)

target_include_directories(StackOverflow
    PRIVATE
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
)
```

The directory is like so

```
./
L include/
    L game.h
    L peca.h
L src/
    L game.cpp
    L peca.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
```

Running

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
$ ./StackOverflow
```

runs without error